# How can I put an icon inside a Input in ReactJS?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, input, icons

I'm new in reactJS, but I want to know how I can put icon inside input element?

I have a FormItem and inside of this an Input, and inside of this input i want to put an icon.

```js
 <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={12}>
    <FormItem
      {...formItemLayout}
      label={intl.formatMessage({ id: `maintenace.link.linkOrigin` })}
    >
      {getFieldDecorator(`officePhone`, {
        initialValue: selectedData_.officePhone
          ? selectedData_.officePhone
          : ""
      })(
        <Input
          name="officePhone"
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
            id: `maintenance.officePhone`
          })}
        />
      )}
    </FormItem>
</Col>
```

If anyone knows, please, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use some lib related to the Ant Design. You can add prefix prop

```
<Input prefix={<SmileOutlined />} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `background` on the input, something like this :

```css
input: {
    background: url(icon.gif) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```